# Vuetify data-table cell coloring

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a vuetify v-data-table, where I would like to colour cells, depending on a condition. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Example:

```
data() {
  return {
    personnel: 'Max Muster',
    column2: {
            qualified: false,
            wish: '',
            allocation: '',
          },
    column3: {
            qualified: true,
            wish: '',
            allocation: '',
          },
```

So I would like column 2 to be red (qualified=false) and column 3 to be green (qualified=true).

Obviously there are more lines, where the same applies and there will be more columns too.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `item` slot which allows you to create a custom row - meaning you'll be able to apply conditional classes.

Check out an example here where I use Vuetify's example data-set: https://codepen.io/ianteoyy-the-flexboxer/pen/JjOxjMQ

Comment: Not what I was looking for. Your example shows the whole row coloured. I need to have single cells coloured depending on conditions.

Comment: @Ch.Osswald in that case, place the conditional classes within the <td> elements rather than the <tr>. I've updated the codepen.